# how to save pointer with different ACL of Parent object on Parse?

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform, relationship, acl

I have a very hard issue here; I looked the Parse.com js SDK at least three times now but can't figure this out.

I have a Question Class with text, user, comments.
I have a Comment Class with text, user.

Comments are placed in an array of pointers to the Question Class.

```
Question = Parse.Object.extend('Question');
question = new Question();
question.set('text', 'my first question');

// the user posting the question
var acl = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()); 
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
question.setACL(acl);
question.set('user', Parse.User.current());
question.save();
```

Here everything fine. Now another user log's in the app and posts a comment

```
question; // let's asume the question is fetched
Comment = Parse.Object.extend('Comment');
comment = new Comment();
comment.set('text', 'my first comment on the first question');

// the user posting the comment (another user)
// this user has public read rights on the comment but not write rights
// he has the write rights on his comment though

var acl = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()); 
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
comment.setACL(acl);
comment.set('user', Parse.User.current());
comment.save();

// comment is saved we can now add it to the question's array
question.add(comment);
question.save(); // this is where everything fails...
```

it says user don't have the right to write on the question object which is normal but how can the comment be saved if I don't save the question with the new array?

Comment: Why don't you just give them both write access and secure the editing of the Question client side? If not, you can always create a join table which both users have read/write permissions on. Then just use the join table to store the Id of the parent Question and child Comment and retrieve all comments associate with the question by querying the join table, retrieving all of the comment IDs and then querying the Comments table with those IDs.

Comment: secure editing client side in js is not secure because anybody can just play with the console bypass this. For the join table the problem remains because (https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#relations-many-to-many) the parent is still the one being saved

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1: JOIN TABLE**

```
question; // let's asume the question is fetched

//GET OBJECT ID HERE WHEN FETCHING QUESTION
questionID = question.id;


Comment = Parse.Object.extend('Comment');
comment = new Comment();
comment.set('text', 'my first comment on the first question');

// the user posting the comment (another user)
// this user is have public read rights on the comment but not write rights
// he has the write rights on his comment though

var acl = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()); 
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
comment.setACL(acl);
comment.set('user', Parse.User.current());

//NEW CODE HERE TOO
comment.save().then(function(results){
  commentID = results.id;
});;

// NOW ADD COMMENT AND QUESTION TO JOIN TABLE BY OBJECTID
JoinTable = Parse.Object.extend('JoinTable');
entry = new JoinTable();
entry.set('questionID', questionID);
entry.set('commentID', commentID);
entry.save().then(function(results){
//MIGHT WANT TO PUSH THE NEW COMMENT ONTO THE COMMENTS ARRAY 
//WHICH YOU ARE DISPLAYING WITH YOUR QUESTION
});
```

Now, when you load a question just do a query on the join table by the questionID which will give you all commentIDs associated with the question. Then query the comments table with that commentID, load, and display those results.

**OPTION 2: SAVE QUESTION ID WITH COMMENT**

```
question; // let's asume the question is fetched

//GET OBJECT ID HERE WHEN FETCHING QUESTION
questionID = question.id;


Comment = Parse.Object.extend('Comment');
comment = new Comment();
comment.set('text', 'my first comment on the first question');

// the user posting the comment (another user)
// this user is have public read rights on the comment but not write rights
// he has the write rights on his comment though

var acl = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()); 
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
comment.setACL(acl);
comment.set('user', Parse.User.current());
//SET QUESTION ID ON COMMENT
comment.set('parent', questionID);


//NEW CODE HERE TOO
comment.save().then(function(results){
  commentID = results.id;
});;
```

Now, when you query for the Questions, also query the comments table and retrieve all comments with the current questions objectID as their 'parent'.

**You Mentioned in Comment**

That parse is not relational. Parse is based on MongoDB which is a NoSQL database. However, you can do relations "by reference."

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

**TO RETRIEVE BOTH QUESTIONS AND COMMENTS**

```
//First get the question
var Question = Parse.Object.extend("Question");
var query = new Parse.Query(Question);
query.equalTo("questionID", questionID);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
     //You will have to check results and see if it returns an array
     //If it does you will need to use results[0].id to select 1st
     //element in array. The follow code is if results is an Object

     var JoinTable = Parse.Object.extend("JoinTable");
     var query = new Parse.Query(JoinTable);
     query.equalTo("parentID", questionID);
     query.find({
        success: function(results) {
        //this should return an array, loop through the array to get
        //all of the IDs then, pe## Heading ##rform a compound query with all of 
        //IDs

      },
     error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }
    });
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

**HOWEVER, WRITING THAT CODE WAS INCREDIBLY ANNOYING AND UNNECESSARY SO I RECOMMEND OPTION TWO HERE IS HOW TO DO THAT**

```
//First get the question
var Question = Parse.Object.extend("Question");
var query = new Parse.Query(Question);
query.equalTo("questionID", questionID);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
     //You will have to check results and see if it returns an array
     //If it does you will need to use results[0].id to select 1st
     //element in array. The follow code is if results is an Object

    var questionID = results.id;

     var Comments = Parse.Object.extend("Comments");
     var query = new Parse.Query(Comments);
     query.equalTo("parentID", questionID);
     query.find({
        success: function(results) {
         //This returns your comments to be shared with your view

      },
     error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }
    });
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

You will notice I stopped writing out the actual code at the forEach loop on the commentIDs because I realized how unnecessary it was. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Could you do an exemple of query to get the question and it's comments ?

Because, well, it would be okay if we were in a regular relational DB case, but it's isn't the case, there's nothing is "joins" on parse.com since it uses a no sql db (perhaps mondo ou cassendra). That's why their sdk saves pointers and not id's i guess

Comment: thanks, well this was how effectively i thought it would look like and the problem with this is that there's no eager loading. Asuming i have to load 10 questions + their answers... that's 1 main + 10 sub requests = 11 requests to the api which is not so efficient. Well i got through this doing a Cloud code function.

Comment: I was just about to say you should just do a cloud code function. Lol ;-)

Comment: haha i think most things on Parse needs to be done with Cloud Code. By the way, what i meant by << there's nothing like "joins" >> was that you couldn't join tables with one single query (your exemple demonstrates it perfectly)